# Error on employee>department>department settings Odoo/OpenERP

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

Accidentally I deleted my administrator from the department from employee module. And I recreated the administrator account manually. Now while I going throw the department setting of every department it shows an error which mentions below. Kindly help me to over come to this issue without uninstalling the module.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 101, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 885, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 877, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
    return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 670, in call_kw_multi
    recs = self.with_context(context or {}).browse(ids)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-10.0.post20170615-py2.7.egg/odoo/models.py", line 4892, in with_context
    context = dict(args[0] if args else self._context, **kwargs)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 20; 2 is required
```

Comment: update odoo base module.

Comment: not working.. @heroi